# Error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following the react js tutorial, and I keep running into this issue

```
import React from "react";
import NewsCard from "../NewsCard/NewsCard";
const NewsCards = ({ articles }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {articles.map((article, i) => {
        <NewsCard />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewsCards;
```

Comment: As the error states, `articles` is `undefined`.  Which means no such value was provided for this component.  Can you provide an example which demonstrates otherwise?  Please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate specifically where you are supplying a value to `articles` and why it shouldn't be `undefined`.

Comment: Several people have solved this in the answers below, On another note, could you provide the component which renders the NewsCards component? If it is working in the tutorial but not for you, it might be a problem in how you provide the articles props to the NewsCards component.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your articles does not have default value as [].
You can change as follow. And you should give key attribute when using `map` function.

```
const NewsCards = ({ articles }) => {
  const data = articles ? articles : []
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((article, i) => {
        <NewsCard key={article.id}/>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still need help, just like what the previous answers said, make sure that `articles` is initialized/defined by using the `&&` operator to make that check. Also, based upon what you wrote, the map method is returning `undefined` since you specified a function body (using the function body bracket notation {} ) without a `return` statement. So instead write the map method like this:

```
<div>
{articles && articles.map((article, i) => <NewsCard />)}
</div>
```

or like this:

```
<div>
{articles && articles.map((article, i) => {
   return <NewsCard />
})}
</div>
```

The first example has a implicit return since an arrow function is being used and a function body is not present (there are no function body brackets { }).

Answer (score 0):

Probably articles is not initialized when you try to map throught it. Try this:

```
{articles?.map((article, i) => {
        <NewsCard />;
      })}
```

OR

```
{articles && articles.map((article, i) => {
        <NewsCard />;
      })}
    </div>
```

That way you will first make sure if articles exist

Comment: This won't render as the callback inside the map is not returning the component

Answer (score 0):

This means that the articles prop is undefined.

There are several ways to solve this. The first and easiest way is by implementing the following logic:

```
{articles?.length ? articles.map((article, i) => <NewsCard />) : "There are no articles here."}
```

Another way to solve this is by implementing React `proptypes` - you can read about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Third and "hardest" (but probably best) way to solve this is by using a static type checking tool. Flow comes to mind, but you can use TypeScript too.

Comment: Under the same runtime conditions, this code would produce the error: *"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."*

Comment: Ah yes, I did not add a question mark before the dot. Will edit.